# CSS (Firefox) - How to use backdrop-filter and clip-path toghether?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I want to have a color filter on half of my webpage. I tried to obtain this by applying on the whole page a fixed div with a backdrop filter and then cutting the div shape with clip-path.

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#front {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.5);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%) !important;
  backdrop-filter: invert(100%);
  width: 600px;
}

#back {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="back"></div>
<div id="front"></div>
```

This code is working well in chrome: the "front" div is placed on the "back" one and applies its backdrop filter to the visible portion of it.

If ran on firefox (v89.0.1), the clip path is cutting the div but the backdrop filter still gets applied on the original (rectangular) shape.

You can also visit [this codepen](https://codepen.io/kodeeo/pen/RwpmOvp) from the two different browsers to see the problem.

how can I combine those two rules to obtain the effect I desire?

Comment: firefox doesn't support backdrop-filter so even without clip-path you will have issues

Answer (score 2):

As of now, Firefox had enabled backdrop-filter (again) for quite some time, and it seems to work reasonably. But there is still a problem in combination with clip-path in Firefox.
I had set 'clip-path: padding-box' to the body of a page I'm working on trying to achieve an unrelated effect. As the body had no padding, and the effect I was trying to achieve didn't work with CSS only, I simply forgot about the clip-path, as it had no effect by itself. (I would have cleaned up before deploying)

It took me quite some time to figure out, that the reason FF was not showing any kind of backdrop-filter on the page was that clip-path.

I could easily fix it for me, but there seems to be a general issue in FF in regard to clip-path in combination with backdrop-filter. (Chrome did work just fine.)

When I find the time I will investigate a little deeper and file a bug-report, just now I thought, that this answer might help someone in a similar situation to save some time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable `backdrop-filter` first as it is disabled by default in Firefox.

- Open a new Firefox tab and type `about:config` in the address bar. Press Enter.
- You should see a warning. Click on the button saying Accept the Risk and Continue. This message is shown because, on this page, all experimental features are present which may produce glitches when enabled and hinder performance, including the `backdrop-filter`.
  [image]
- Type `layout.css.backdrop-filter.enabled` in the search bar. You should see the value is set to false. On the extreme right, there is a reversible arrow (or whatever you call it). Click it to change the value to true.
  [image]
  [image]
- Next, type `gfx.webrender.all` in the search bar. It should also be false by default. Change it to true similarly.

Done!

Comment: Thanks, bu I already did that! Now my problem is about using this property combined with the clip-path property to give a shape to the backgdrop-filter effect. Backdrop-filter seems to be ignoring its element's shape (given by clip-path) and just assumes it's rectangular